# Additional checkout not displaying on product pages

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, addtocart, paypal-express

I've added the Paypal express checkout on my magento application, the paypal express checkout displays on the default product template, but it is not showing on my custom product template.

I dug further and found that the default product template calls the paypal code when the `getchildhtml('addtocart')` code gets executed. Where my custom product template is calling the same `getchildhtml('addtocart'`)code the paypal code is not showing.

Is there an xml configuration that I'm missing? Is there any areas that I files that I should take a look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look into the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypal.xml` you will see that there is some layout xml code for the handle `catalog_product_view`. This should be used for adding in the express information to the product details page.

I would suggest that your theme either removes the block set or simply does not have this code in place.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.info.addtocart.paypal.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>PayPal Express Checkout Shortcut Wrapper</label>
            <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="product.info.addtocart.paypal" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
                <action method="setIsInCatalogProduct"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <update handle="SHORTCUT_popup" />
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="paypal/logo" name="paypal.partner.right.logo" template="paypal/partner/logo.phtml">
            <!--action method="setLogoType"><value>wePrefer_150x60</value></action-->
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```